# Closing socket is resetting http connection

Tags: c++, sockets, http, winsock2

This is for a c++ implementation of http using winsock2. I'm sending the required headers, but because of the flow of the application, I cannot know the length of the content.

According to the protocol, closing the connection should signal a normal end to the body as long as I specify `Connection: close`in the headers, which I'm doing.

Right after sending the body, I call `closesocket(socket)` to close the connection, but chrome puts out an error saying `The connection was reset.`.

If I comment that out, it displays the body, but never finishes loading since the connection is still active.

Am I closing the socket in the wrong way? Or am I missing something with the http protocol with regards to the end of content?

I've been reading up on this all day and I'm coming up with nothing

Comment: The usual mechanism for sending the response of unknown length is [`Transfer-Encoding: chunked`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8872988/properly-close-a-tcp-socket

Comment: @jarmod Thanks, I wasn't reading the socket stream after closing, which was causing the error. I just needed to shutdown, read and then close.